Icons with links not working on mobile menu in Divi Theme
I have designed this website and facing the issues that the icons in primary menu and the button "ENQURE" in sticky bottom footer aren't working when clicking on mobile but working when I visit the website on desktop.
I have the row css added "display:flex" on mobile header.
The Phone Icon in the mobile menu has an ID link "#Contact" which works fine on desktop view.
The Whatsapp icon in the mobile also works fine on desktop but doesn't work on mobile.
The "ENQUIRE" button at the sticky bar works fine on desktop but not working on mobile.
Can anyone help me?
website link : https://diamondsbydanubeproperties.com/
